# How to check this now famous graph has chromatic number 5?

Tags: graphs-and-networks

Just read [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1804.02385.pdf) from Aubrey de Grey, who used Mathematica to find a unit distance graph of chromatic number 5.

Here's the graph he discovered:

```
g = CloudGet@"https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/d44eaba1-37f3-4f82-8d27-a547da117f8d";
```

How can we check this graph does indeed have chromatic number 5?

**Links:**

- The quanta article announcement: https://www.quantamagazine.org/decades-old-graph-problem-yields-to-amateur-mathematician-20180417/

Comment: I implemented a basic minimum colouring function for IGraph/M (will be in the next version due in 1-2 weeks) based on `SatisfiabilityInstances`. With this approach, checking 4-colourability of this particular graph is already too slow.  I just wanted to mention this in case someone tries things in the same direction (`SatisfiableQ`, etc.).

Comment: There was a post about this on W|C too: http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1320004

Comment: (For 5-colouring, the IGraph/M implementation manages fine and quickly. The problem is with proving that a 4-colouring does not exist, which is extremely slow.)

Comment: With the symmetry breaking heuristic described in the same paper, the timing comes down to 3-4 seconds.  Will update when I get the time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Update:** With IGraph/M 0.3.98 and later, you can now simply use

```
IGChromaticNumber[g]
```

or use

```
IGMinimumVertexColoring[g] // Timing
(* {14.6513, ...} *)
```

to find a minimum colouring.

`IGMinimumVertexColoring` transforms the colouring problem into Boolean satisfiability, and has an option to force a distinct set of colours onto a set of vertices. Usually one would pass a clique, as the colours of a clique must be all distinct.  Doing this can significantly speed up the function (in particular the part that verifies that the graph is not $\chi-1$-colourable).  However, the SAT solver's performance seems to also depend on the *ordering* of clauses.

For this graph, the default heuristic finds the clique `{2, 1, 7}`, and imposes distinct colours on it. But giving the vertices of the clique in a different order (and thus imposing different colours on its vertices) results in different performance.

```
IGMinimumVertexColoring[g, "ForcedColoring" -> {1, 2, 7}]; // Timing
(* {3.89746, Null} *)
```

Thus, if you have hard colouring problems, it is worth experimenting with passing different constraints throught he `"ForcedColoring"` option.

If anyone here can see some pattern in which constraints give generally the best performance, please let me know.

---

**Original answer:**

I have recently implemented minimum vertex colouring for [IGraph/M](http://szhorvat.net/mathematica/IGraphM). It is based on encoding the $k$-colouring problem into a satisfiability one and using  [`SatisfiabilityInstances`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SatisfiabilityInstances.html).  This is based on the suggestions of user [@Juho](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/1152/juho).  The current implementation uses the "Traditional" encoding described e.g. in https://doi.org/10.1016/j.dam.2006.07.016

The version of IGraph/M that includes this function is not yet released, but if you want to play with it, you can contact me privately.  Alternatively, you can look at the implementation of `IGKVertexColoring` here:

https://github.com/szhorvat/IGraphM/blob/master/IGraphM/IGraphM.m#L4369

Simply replace `IGIndexEdgeList[g]` with `List @@@ EdgeList@IndexGraph[g]` to make it work without the rest of the package.

With this function, finding a 5-colouring of this graph is easy:

```
sol = IGKVertexColoring[g, 5]; // Timing
(* {0.116768, Null} *)

Graph[g, GraphStyle -> "BasicBlack", 
 EdgeStyle -> Opacity[0.1], 
 VertexStyle -> Thread[VertexList[g] -> ColorData[97] /@ First[sol]], 
 ImageSize -> Large, VertexSize -> {"Scaled", 0.01}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

However, proving that the chromatic number is 5 requires showing that there is no 4-colouring.  This is possible, but not at all fast.

```
sol = IGKVertexColoring[g, 4]; // Timing
(* {1726.04, Null} *)

sol
(* {} *)
```

As an experiment, I tried the same with the glucose 4.0 SAT solver, and it took 470 seconds—faster, but not dramatically so.

Suggestions for improving on these functions are most welcome.

---

**Update:**

I just updated the implementation in IGraph/M by implementing a heuristic similar to those described in the section "Breaking symmetry" of the mentioned paper.  This means that the GitHub link above now points to a more complex implementation.  But the performance is much better:

```
Max@IGMinimumVertexColoring[g] // Timing
(* {3.96151, 5} *)
```

Verifying the chromatic number takes only 4 seconds now.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that using the `updateIGraphM[] ` install script also installs the needed `igraph` files? Or do I separately need to install some version of `igraph`? And if the latter, which? At http://igraph.org I find R/igraph, C/igraph, and python-igraph; and for macOS, which I'm using, I also find a MacPorts port called simply igraph.

Comment: @murray You do not need to download anything from igraph.org.  Everything is in the IGraph/M paclet. However, the *current* version does not include the *minimum* vertex colouring functionality. If you are interested in playing with this, drop me an email and I'll send you a work-in-progress version.